# Can a maven build tell if it is multi-module

Tags: maven

I have a multi-module maven build, with a structure like

```
a/
 pom.xml
 b/
  pom.xml
  c/
   pom.mxl
  d/pom.xml
 e/
  pom.xml
```

Some of the analysis plugins are slow, so I would like to skip them when running building multiple modules  (`cd a; mvn install`) but not a single module (`cd a/b/c; mvn install`).  In the single module build, I might look at the generated warnings and fix them, but with the multi-module build, they I won't look at them,  since the full build literally builds dozens of modules.

Is there a way to determine if I am building multiple modules from within the build?

I am hoping for something like `reactor.build` is defined in all modules when I run from `/a` but not defined when I run from `/a/b/c`.

All I was able to find when I googled was how to set up a multi-module build or only build some of the projects, which is not what I am looking for.

*Goals*

I understand the maven build cycle.  I want to be able to add something like this to my pom root pom:

```
  <properties>
     <skipSlowPlugin>${multi.project.build}</skipSlowPlugin>
  <properties>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.slow</groupId>
          <artifactId>analysis-tool</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
          <configuration>
             <skip>${skipSlowPlugin}</skip>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugin>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

If I run the build from `/a/b/c`, `multi.project.build` will be false and the plugin will run.  If I run from `/a` or `/a/b`, then `multi.project.build` will be true and the plugin will not run.

In every case, I want to build everything under the current directory, so `--pm` and `--am` are irrelevant.

Comment: What kind of analysis plugins are you talking of? You build a multi module build from the root...If you like to build only parts of it: Best is to do first a `mvn clean install` from root and now you can use `mvn -pl a/b clean package` also helpful are `--also-make` which means to build the list of project needed by the given list furthermore `--also-make-dependents` which builds the list of projects which depend on the given list of projects..

Comment: The most significant one is that we run spot bugs on source code.  `-pl` and `--also-make` address a different problem.  I know how to just compile `a/b/c`.  What I want is something like `mvn resources compile test install` when I run from `/a` and `mvn resource compile test spotbugs install` when I run from `/a/b/c`, where those are the plugins that it runs.

Comment: You seemed to have no idea how the life cycle in Maven works. Please read the documentation https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Setting_Up_Your_Project_to_Use_the_Build_Lifecycle

Comment: @khmarbaise his ignorance notwithstanding, its a perfectly valid question. I want to run dsm-maven-plugin as yet doesn't support multi-module build. There is no enforcer rule I can see that will detect and prevent running this if it were a multi-module build